# Angularjs Option value doesn't show in windows tablet(IE browser) in select box

Tags: windows, angularjs, tablet

I am binding the data in select box input option field, it works fine in all browsers and OS, but it's not working in Windows Tablet ?

Do anybody have idea ? why it is not working for tablet IE browser?

### My code :

```
  <select ng-model="user[teach.id]">
   <option value="0">Select rank</option>
   <option value="{{rank.id}}" ng-selected="user[teach.id] == rank.id" ng-repeat="(i,rank) in rankList">{{rank.rank_name}}
     </option>
</select>
```

> Issue: On windows tablet it shows "{{rank.rank_name}}" as it is, it
>   will not show actual rank_name value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved, just need to add

```
 label={{rank.rank_name}}
```

Answer (score 1):

please, try at your Windows Tablet using **ng-options** to test:

```
        <select ng-model="teach"
            ng-options="opt as opt.rank_name for opt in rankList">
```

(similar code at this link: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/za3Bk/))